# Additional common actions for bake

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-bake

What is better way to bake an additional common actions (like enable, moveup, movedown and other) additionally to index, view, add, edit, delete? Is there a trick that I have missed in the manuals? Or proper way will be modify CAKE/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Shell/Task/ControllerTask.php by making branch?

Comment: Have you read **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/bake/development.html** ?

Answer (score 2):

After advice of jose_zap in #cakephp chanell at irc.freenode.net and some experiments I have found solution.

1) to copy

```
APP/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Template/Bake/Controller/controller.ctp
```

to my plugin as

```
APP/plugins/MY_PLUGIN/src/Template/Bake/Controller/controller.ctp
```

2) to modify in following lines (commented original actions parsing and added my own):

```
//  foreach($actions as $action) {
//    echo $this->element('Controller/' . $action);
//  }

    $themeActions = ['index', 'view', 'add', 'edit', 'delete', 'moveup','movedown', 'recover', 'enable', 'disable', 'copy'];
    foreach($themeActions as $action) {
        echo $this->element($this->theme.'.Controller/' . $action);
    }
```

3) to copy all files from

```
APP/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Template/Bake/Element/Controller/*
```

to

```
APP/plugins/Tools/src/Template/Bake/Element/Controller/*
```

and add my own actions (like 'moveup','movedown', 'recover', 'enable', 'disable', 'copy' and so on)

Thats' all.